# how to get feed links i.e. .rss .xml etc from google feed API

Tags: php, javascript, search-engine

I want to use the Google feed API to search for news feeds however i don't have any previous experience of using an API so i was thinking somebody can help out about building an application where users can enter their query and get the corresponding feed/feeds matching it.Basically my emphasis is upon getting the feed links.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Feed API is [typically accessed using a REST with JSON interface](http://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-own-rss-reader-using-google-feed-api/). Meaning you make requests, similar to how make requests in your browser using the address bar, and it returns data which is normally in JSON (Javascript Object Notation) format.

As an example, try putting this into your address bar:

[http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=&q=http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=&q=http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml)

It uses the Feed API to return front page news from BBC. Now, javascript isn't the *only* way to do access the API. Using the same method of connecting, in PHP you could use something like:

```
// Create REST request URL
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=&q=http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml";
// Make request and get resulting JSON response
$json_feed = file_get_contents($url);
// Dump it to the screen so we can see it
var_dump($json_feed);
```

You can return results in JSON, XML, or Mixed and using PHP can then use the data for any processing you may need to do. If you are using Zend Framework or are familiar with implementing any of their components, they have the [GData component](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata/) which is a PHP library for accessing Google Data APIs.

For more information, check out the [Feed API's Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide).

Comment: i am trying to get something like http://www.ctrlq.org/rss. It is also using the Google feed API implementing the search engine concept. I am willing to achieve a similar sought of thing.